# ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity, sass-loader

I'm running the following command:

`ng build --prod --aot --base-href ./`

And receiving;

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

$clr-popover-box-shadow-color: rgba(clr-getColor(dark), 0.25);
                              ^
      Argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color
      in /Users/allan/git/dcfrontend/node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/_variables.global.scss (line 84, column 32)
```

I'm on Angular 7 and Clarity 1.04.

Extract from my `angular.json`:

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.css",
          "node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css",
          "node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-solarizedlight.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/lato-font/css/lato-font.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
          "node_modules/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js",
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",
          "node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js",
          "node_modules/prismjs/prism.js",
          "node_modules/prismjs/components/prism-typescript.min.js",
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"
        ]
```

Comment: show us please the `_variables.global.scss` thx

Comment: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/utils/_variables.global.scss

Comment: what does `clr-getColor(dark)` return? It can't be a valid color because else u would't get these error, may a wrong format?

Comment: How do I test that?  this happens during the build..

Answer (score 31):

I was also getting the same error and i solved it by running the below npm command:

```js
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install node-sass
```

Worked for me :) Just try this if "npm rebuild node-sass" not worked

Answer (score 4):

This solve my issue `npm install --save-dev --unsafe-perm node-sass`

Answer (score 3):

check for the supported version. As on date I had node 12.x installed on my machine and spent an hour running `npm install node-sass` and `npm rebuild node-sass` with `--force` and `--save-dev` hints.

Nothing worked until I uninstalled the node 12.x and installed node 10.x. So if you're hitting the same problem and could not get it to work, try following

- Check if your Node version (Run node -v) if it's higher than 10.x
- Uninstall the Node 12.x from your machine
- Download and Install Node 10.x
- Restart the console/editor (not required for all and may work without this step)

Comment: Helped me after so much time wasting. Seems like never version can't do it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use NVM to downgrade your node version - 99% of these errors are coming from a version clash between node-sass supported node versions and what you are running on your system. It's still a frustrating one!

Comment: I downgraded to 10.16.3, but still I was facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if someone needs to see this
`npm rebuild node-sass`
would not work out of the box for some new versions of node like **15.X.X** in my case, the fix for this is to downgrade the node version, in my case I downgraded to version **10.16.3**, then I ran the `npm rebuild node-sass` command and the error does not show again

Answer (score 1):

I am running node -v 12.14.1 on MAC OS and got into this issue when tried to fix npm audit (npm audit fix). After this I got issue and same message. I haven't have option to get lower version of node to try some of suggestions on this page so I tried to re-install node-sass but that did not help. However, **rebuilt dependencies** did help.

I have removed **node_modules** folder, ran  `sudo npm install` (newer Mac OS has some permission issues so do sudo)  than  `npm rebuild node-sass` and it resolved my build issue. I hope this helps someone too if other suggestions on this page did not.

Answer (score 0):

So I got my answer by running `ng serve` instead of `ng build` - this told me which of my own source files actually contained the issue.

I resolved it by replacing the following imports:

```
@import '../../../../node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/helpers.clarity';
@import '../../../../node_modules/@clr/ui/src/color/utils/colors.clarity';
@import '../../../../node_modules/@clr/ui/src/color/utils/contrast-cache.clarity';
@import '../../../../node_modules/@clr/ui/src/color/utils/helpers.clarity';
@import '../../../../node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/variables.clarity';
```

with hardcoded values:

```
$clr-header-height: 2.5rem;
$clr-near-white: #fafafa;
$clr-dark-gray: #565656;
$clr-light-gray: #eee;
```

Comment: Are you building a custom theme for your Clarity app?

Comment: I see. If you end up overriding a lot of the variables it might be easier to do it the way a custom theme can be built. Feel free to ping me if you have questions or issues.

Comment: thanks! The motivation here is purely to get a successful build following an angular update.  This is my next issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356517/error-in-clr-icon-is-not-a-known-element

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasn't running (ng serve) from the root folder of my project.
Moving to the root folder solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I saw this error when we upgraded from Angular 9.x to 12.x. I had multiple versions of Node 12.2 and 12.14 (*). I kept getting this error till I uninstalled 12.2 and did npm install after.