# ERROR in : 'clr-icon' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Running the following command:

`ng build --prod --base-href ./`

I get:

```
ERROR in : 'clr-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'clr-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'clr-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("spinner spinner-sm spinner-inverse" [style.display]="loading ? 'inline-block' : 'none'"></span>
    [ERROR ->]<clr-icon clrSignpostTrigger shape="check" size="20" class="is-info" [style.display]="!loading && req")
```

I'm on Angular 7 and Clarity 1.04.

Extract from my `angular.json`:

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.css",
          "node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css",
          "node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-solarizedlight.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/lato-font/css/lato-font.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
          "node_modules/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js",
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",
          "node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js",
          "node_modules/prismjs/prism.js",
          "node_modules/prismjs/components/prism-typescript.min.js",
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"
        ]
```

Any ideas for how I can debug?

Answer (score 4):

`clr-icon` is a custom element but you probably know this.

Can you try adding this to your `polyfills.ts` file ( it should be at the same level as the `app/` directory if you generated with the AngularCLI tool.

```
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements';
import '@clr/icons';
```

Then, strip down the scripts array in your `angular.json` file be empty and see if it builds. If it does start putting the other scripts listed scripts (minus this: `"node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"` and this: `"node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",`) one by one to make sure they aren't causing any issues.

Comment: I added those 2 lines to polyfills, and removed ALL scripts from angular.json, same result :-/

Comment: how did you generate your project and add Clarity to it?

Comment: This happens when you have a Clarity icon but haven't included the Clarity Icons NgModule in your module. Perhaps you are building your project and including very specific modules? If so, you can just use `ClarityModule` instead in all of your NgModules to avoid this.

Comment: Hurrah - that did it!  I had a `mycustom.module.ts`, which DID have ClarityModule in the import statement but NOT in the `import` array  of `NgModule`.  Feel free to add as an answer!

Comment: thanks @hippeelee.  The project is a very old one, that I'm trying to upgrade to Angular 7 - so wasn't built with a recent CLI unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Import `ClrIconModule` to your `app.module.ts` or if you have specific module import it like example bellow.

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ClrIconModule } from '@clr/angular';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes), ClrIconModule]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

so you can use `<clr-icon>` in your component:

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="main-container">
  <header class="header header-6">
    <div class="branding">
      <clr-icon shape="vm-bug"></clr-icon>
      <span class="title">Project Clarity</span>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area">
      ...
    </div>
    <nav class="sidenav">
      ...
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in newer versions of Clarity it is called CdsIconModule, prefix changed from Clr to Cds in many cases...