# The `/deep/` selector is not working using sass-loader in my VueJS application

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2

In my Vue 2.6.10 webpack application I am trying to add SASS as our team wants to migrate our legacy application from LESS to SCSS. In my `package.json` I have installed these to my `devDependencies` per these [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/):

- sass (v.1.32.8)
- sass-loader (v10.1.1)

Then installed `node-sass` (v5.0.0) to my `dependencies`.

My `node` version is: v15.4.0. According to these [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) this is the correct version for `node-sass` v5+.

In my Vue components I am trying to use the `/deep/`, `::v-deep`, or `>>>` selectors. I threw together a working [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-tdd-1y914?file=/src/App.vue) where I have a `ParentComp.vue` target a `ChildComp.vue`'s inner styles using `/deep/` like this:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .parent-container {
    & /deep/ .child-comp {
      background-color: tomato;
      color: white;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Yay! It works great in my playground using the same versions of things that I have control over in that playground.

In my application when I try this exact same setup I get this compile error:

```
./src/components/MenuBarComp.vue (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?
{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?
{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"id":"data-v-4630c6ac","scoped":true,"sourceMap":true}!
./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?
{"additionalData":"/n          @import /"@/styles/_variables.scss/";/n        ","sourceMap":true}!
./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/MenuBarComp.vue)


Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected selector.
   ╷
77 │   & /deep/ .child-test{
   │     ^
   ╵
  src/components/MenuBarComp.vue 77:5  root stylesheet
```

According to many other [suggestions](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/913) which I have tried, I should try using `::v-deep` or `>>>`. When I try to use these selectors it compiles fine and no longer throws an exception, but nothing happens. No CSS is actually rendered like `.parent[data-23423423] .child {}`. But then I see [other articles](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68355036671/) about how this is not supported in SCSS.

So then I go back to trying to figure out what could cause this error and I have tried dozens of things over the course of several days to try and fix this issue like:

- [downgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813386/4826740) node-sass / sass / sass-loader versions to other versions to try and get things to work
- `npm rebuild node-sass --force`
- `rimraf`ing `node_modules`
- Clearing entire `npm cache` and many other things

I already have several pre-existing CSS related packages in my `package.json`:

- css-loader (v.3.1.0)
- less (v3.0.4)
- less-loader (v4.1.0)
- mini-css-extract-plugin (v0.6.0)
- optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin (v5.0.3)
- postcss-import (v11.0.0)
- postcss-loader (v2.0.8)
- postcss-url (v7.2.1)
- vue-style-loader (v3.0.1)

Finally here is how my loaders are setup in webpack:

```
  function generateLoaders(loader, loaderOptions) {
    const loaders = options.usePostCSS
      ? [cssLoader, postcssLoader]
      : [cssLoader];

    if (loader) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: loader + '-loader',
        options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
          sourceMap: options.sourceMap,
        }),
      });
    }

    // Extract CSS when that option is specified
    // (which is the case during production build)
    if (options.extract) {
      return [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader].concat(loaders);
    } else {
      return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders);
    }
  }

  // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass'),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass', {
      additionalData: `
          @import "@/styles/_variables.scss";
        `,
    }),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus'),
  };
};
```

How can I get the `/deep/` selector to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because **[`/deep/`](https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/2185)** is not supported by `sass`. You need to explicitly set your `sass-loader` to use `node-sass` like this:

```
loader: 'sass-loader', options: { implementation: require('node-sass')
```

`sass-loader` has a note on [their page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) that says:

> Beware the situation when node-sass and sass were installed! **By
> default the sass-loader prefers sass.** In order to avoid this situation
> you can use the implementation option.
>
> The implementation options either accepts sass (Dart Sass) or
> node-sass as a module.

So your specific code would end up being as `sass-loader` uses:

```
scss: generateLoaders('sass', {
  implementation: require('node-sass'),
  additionalData: `
      @import "@/styles/_variables.scss";
    `,
}),
```

Comment: Well. Vuetify uses /deep/, and recommends to use sass instead of node-sass... dependency hell

Comment: This post save me... In my case I found /deep/ issues in Angular 7 project.   This post guide me that I have Dart-sass install on my global node_modules which make sass-loader to use dart-sass instead of node-sass.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the new angular builds face the same issue due to angular-build version mismatch.
There we can use as below,

**:host ::ng-deep** instead of **/deep/**